# AddTarget Function on TableView Cell Element is not working(Unrecognized selector sent to instance)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4.2

I am trying to make a radioButton like functionality using tableviews.So i when i try to addTarget to a button that i have added in a custom cell, the application crashes at runtime, with error.unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe873052000' I have searched alot. I added addTarget on a sample button and it's working. but with this, it's not working. I will post my code here, so you guys can have look please.
Thank you in advance.

I have tried most of the solution, to work around this. if anyone could have a look. or refer me to any code snippet to achieve radio button functionality with table view, because i have to make the at runtime with data i am getting from Api's

```
Code For Custom Cell Class

import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var drinkName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var radioButton: UIButton!



}

Code For Main View Controller.
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

var drinks : [String] = Array()
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var test: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    drinks.append("Coke")
    drinks.append("Sprite")
    drinks.append("Fanta")

    test.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testing), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return drinks.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell

     cell.drinkName.text = drinks[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)



    return cell
}

@objc func pressButton( sender: UIButton)
{
    print("Button Pressed")
    //This gives error
}

 @objc func testing() {
    print("Button Clicked")
    //this Add target is working. written it to test
}
```

}

If anyone can point out the problem. Or refer me to some code snippet, on how to achieve radio button functionality using tableviews. It will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure each cell has the ability to add a radio button?

Comment: This is the line thats crashing?    `cell.radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)`

Comment: I am adding a button. i will write the radio button functionality mySelf.  i will change the images for button. when it's selected.

Comment: Exactly Yes. @Aggressor

Comment: Is the `radioButton` outlet properly set? (it should be a filled in circle, not white)

Comment: Yes, they are properly set. The table view DataSource and delegates are also set. I just can't get around the problem.

Comment: Can you do a print statement on the `cell.radioButton` before you try to add target, comment out the line where you add target, and paste the print out

Comment: yes, it's printing this. Optional(<UIButton: 0x7fe45f806fc0; frame = (321 8; 25 25); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000041e500>>)

Comment: Ok now uncomment the statement when you addTarget. I want to see if the crash happens right away, or if there is a nil cell somewhere

Comment: I'm assuming you have many cells yes? Does this crash happen on cell 1 or are there certain cells its crashing on?

Comment: Also add this line before you add target: `print(cell.radioButton.respondsToSelector(Selector("addTarget")))`

Comment: Here is the exception, 2019-01-11 00:08:03.159938+0500 TableView Testing[3247:72934] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TableView_Testing.CustomTableViewCell radioClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb91f84e400'
and it's crashing on every cell.

Comment: Does it print false when you check if it responds to selector?

Comment: It's showing an error: Value of type 'UIButton?' has no member 'respondsToSelector'

Comment: Ah ok. Can you paste a picture of your outlets from your xib. I want to see the radio connection from the storyboard

Comment: Is it possible to link to your full ViewController class or update with the current code? The error doesn't appear to correspond to the code here. '[TableView_Testing.CustomTableViewCell radioClick:' means 'CustomTableViewCell' doesn't respond to 'radioClick'.